# Why is a comma used in this sentence instead of a semicolon?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, commas, semicolons

> LONDON—The U.K. government announced sweeping tax increases and spending cuts on Thursday**,** *becoming the first major Western economy to start sharply limiting its spending growth after years of ramped-up fiscal stimulus during the pandemic and recent energy subsidies.*

The sentence after the comma is not complete because of no subject and no verb. The sentence is more like explaining the first one. Why does the writer use a comma instead of a semicolon?

Comment: A semicolon is used to join two complete sentences. The clause starting 'beginning' is not a sentence.

Comment: Is it correct to put the comma before "becoming"? I looked up the usage of commas, and there is no one way to explain the comma here.

Comment: Where do you think it should be put, and why?

Comment: _He reached across the table, knocking over a vase with his elbow._ It's all one sentence - the second part states the effect of the action described in the first part.

Answer (score 0):

A semicolon is used to join two complete sentences that are related in some way.  You can often replace a semicolon with "because" or "so".

> The UK government has raised taxes; it needs more money.

(In this example the second part is potentially a complete sentence, but the to sentences are linked, and "because" is implied as the connector.)

In your example, the part starting "becoming" could not be a complete sentence.  So a semicolon would be inappropriate punctuation.